# Why are there no Domain Commands in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Why there are only Domain Events  (not talking about CQRS) in the Domain-Driven Design theory?

Domain Commands like CreateOrder or CollectPayment seem to be a valid concept as well.

Is there a reason for this? Or are commands seen as a subset of events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands are typically the result of a user action. Inside the domain we don’t have user actions, therefor we don’t need commands. Instead we have events which can help us react to things that have happened in the domain *as a result of a user action outside the domain*.

A user clicks on a button and a command is send. When a CommandHandler receives a command, it can create a new aggregate, or make an aggregate by fetching the necessary data from persistence and invoke a method on the aggregate. The invoked methods can emit events.

Comment: Does it mean commands like CollectPayment are not valid constructs? What about cron-scheduled actions (SendNotification etc)?

Comment: Commands and their Handlers live outside of the domain.